# Return a dynamic table using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to create a dynamic table using `react`.
Here is what I have so far...

DataTable.js

```
import React from 'react'
import data from '../data/customerData.json'
import '../styles/dataTable.css'



const DataTable = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          {data.map(dat => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <table className='data-table-container'>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                            <th>Loan Vehicle</th>
                            <th>Time Out</th>
                            <th>Time Due</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{dat.CustomerName}</td>
                            <td>{dat.PhoneNumber}</td>
                            <td>{dat.LoanVehicle}</td>
                            <td>{dat.TimeOut}</td>
                            <td>{dat.TimeDue}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }

export default DataTable
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import DataTable from '../components/DataTable';
import '../styles/calendar.css'




const Home = () => {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());
  let today = new Date().toDateString()
  return (
    <>
      <div className='date-display'>
        <h3 className='current-date-display'>{today}</h3>
      </div>
      <Calendar onChange={onChange} value={value} />
      <DataTable/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Here is what that renders in the browser..

[image: Browser Render]

So currently in my `DataTable.js` component I am using `.map` to loop over the `data` in `customerData.json` which works fine. The issue I have is as you can see from the screenshot img the table headers in the `<th>` tags render with each loop.
My question is how can I display the `<th>` tags once and keep the loop to display the `<td>` tag content..
See expected output below..

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating many tables, in a loop.  Instead of outputting the entire table in the `.map()` body, only output the rows.  Keep everything else static outside of that loop:

```
return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <table className='data-table-container'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Phone Number</th>
                    <th>Loan Vehicle</th>
                    <th>Time Out</th>
                    <th>Time Due</th>
                </tr>
                {data.map(dat => {
                  return (
                    <tr>
                        <td>{dat.CustomerName}</td>
                        <td>{dat.PhoneNumber}</td>
                        <td>{dat.LoanVehicle}</td>
                        <td>{dat.TimeOut}</td>
                        <td>{dat.TimeDue}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```

You can make it a little more clear for yourself by explicitly separating `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements:

```
return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <table className='data-table-container'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Loan Vehicle</th>
                        <th>Time Out</th>
                        <th>Time Due</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map(dat => {
                      return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{dat.CustomerName}</td>
                            <td>{dat.PhoneNumber}</td>
                            <td>{dat.LoanVehicle}</td>
                            <td>{dat.TimeOut}</td>
                            <td>{dat.TimeDue}</td>
                        </tr>
                      );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```

You might even add a default "no records found" row when there's no data to display, just for a bit more user experience:

```
return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <table className='data-table-container'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Loan Vehicle</th>
                        <th>Time Out</th>
                        <th>Time Due</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.length > 0 ? data.map(dat => {
                      return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{dat.CustomerName}</td>
                            <td>{dat.PhoneNumber}</td>
                            <td>{dat.LoanVehicle}</td>
                            <td>{dat.TimeOut}</td>
                            <td>{dat.TimeDue}</td>
                        </tr>
                      );
                    }) : <tr><td colspan="5">No records found</td></tr>}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```